# Drawing to canvas using JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, canvas

I am trying to call line info from a json object into a canvas using ajax.  I'm new to json, so I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing this.  Here's what I have so far.

**JSON**

```
{
    "line": {
        "width": 3,
        "stroke": "#FFFFFF",
        "x1": "640.386",
        "y1": "258.163",
        "x2": "816.364",
        "y2": "258.163"
    }   
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("schematic_holder");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "js/app/json/nst.json",
        success: function(result){
            $.each(result.line, function(){
                console.log(result.line);
            })
        },
        complete: function(){
            console.log("Complete!");
        }
    })
})
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <canvas id="schematic_holder"></canvas>
</body>
```

Right now, when I print to the console, I'm getting an undefined error.  Am I calling the object wrong?  I know how to get the lines to draw with canvas, I'm just confused about how to do so from a JSOn file.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: First check what is the response and if it has line child - console.log(result)

Comment: Which line of `js` at `console` returned `undefined` error ? Can include `error` message at OP ?

Comment: @PawełDuda Ok, I'm getting `Object{}` in the console log.  so it's not showing any children.

Comment: @guest271314 line 10

Comment: Then you most likely have incorrect path to json file

Comment: @PawełDuda No `error` handlers, response should be `success` ; see above comment, `line 10 ` , `$.each(result.line, function(){` ?

Comment: @Robert Try adding `contentType:"application/json"` at `$.ajax()` settings; `function(result, textStatus, jqxhr)` , `console.log(result, textStatus, jqxhr.responseJSON)` at `success` handler.

Comment: @pawelduda I though that would be the case,  but if I change the console to be "Success!"  in the success function,  it actually prints.  So it's locating the json file.

Comment: do you have access to the json file?  if so wrap the entire thing in `[ ]`

Comment: @guest271314 that gives `uncaught referenceerror: responseJSON is not defined`

Comment: @jacob I do, I created it. So instead of `{} ` do `[] `?

Comment: no, try to wrap it like this `[{"line":etc....}]`

Comment: @jacob sorry,  that's what I meant.

Comment: @Robert At above comment, `contentType`  should _not_ have effect http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/; omit that as possible issue.

Comment: no prob, glad it worked, I will submit it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the entire json file in brackets `[]`, like this

```
[{
    "line": {
        "width": 3,
        "stroke": "#FFFFFF",
        "x1": "640.386",
        "y1": "258.163",
        "x2": "816.364",
        "y2": "258.163"
    }   
}]
```